# express-session dynamic cookie domain

Tags: node.js, express, session, dns, express-session

I have a number of domains and I'm trying to dynamically set the cookie domain in express-session.

below ".example.com" text works fine in domain.

```
// Sessions
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session)
app.use(session({
    "name": "session",
    "secret": "null",
    "resave": false,
    "saveUninitialized": true
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not wrap the "session" function inside a custom middleware function, like this?

```js
 app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // do here what you want with req,res,next

    let middleware = session({
        "name": "session",
        "secret": "null",
        "resave": false,
        "saveUninitialized": true
    });

    // call middleware function
    middleware(req, res, next);

 });
```

`session` just returns a function, which you can wrap/call inside a custom middleware function, where you get access to the needed properties. (req, res) -> https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L179

Sadly there are no way to access the [`options`](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L88) object from outside, which would allow to manipulate the session instance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out the solution you gave @Marc and this causes a memory leak if you use a session store like Mongodb, because a new connection to it is created each time the app receives a request.
The error:

```
(node:4333) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 disconnect listeners added to [MongoStore]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:4333) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connect listeners added to [MongoStore]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

To fix that, you might want to memoize the middleware function returned after the first go so you only have one listener on the store:

```js
let memo = {middle: null};
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // do here what you want with req,res,next

    let middleware; 
    if(memo.middle){
      // call if it already exists
      middleware = memo.middle;
    } else {
      middleware = session({
          "name": "session",
          "secret": "null",
          "resave": false,
          "saveUninitialized": true,
          "store": mongoStore,
      });
      // store instance we get otherwise.
      memo.middle = middleware;
    }
    // call middleware function
    middleware(req, res, next);

 });
```

This reflects the same behaviour as passing the middleware via `app.use(session(config))`, which is the goal of the last part of the middleware. Just like subsequent requests passing through `app.use(session(config))` will reuse the same middleware and not call `session(config)` again, subsequent calls on this middleware would use the initial value of middleware returned from `session(config)` as memoised.

Error handling is up to you to ensure a good UX.