# Is there a way to access `req` object in the session function in express to use dynamic domains?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server, pm2

I want to add another domain to my routes. So multiple domains can acces the routes and I will be able to detect which domain the request is coming from and handle them accordingly. I want to set up sessions with dynamic domains and use HTTPS. Is there any way I can use dynamic domains in the cookie section below? I want to substitute "mydomain.com" below with "mydomain2.com". Any way to access the `req` object ins the `session` method below.

```
 server.use(session({
        secret: 'a;ldfnrlkf332',
        resave: true,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
        saveUninitialized: false,
        // cookie : {secure : false, domain : "lvh.me"}
        cookie: { 
            // secure: false, 
            secure : process.envNODE_ENV === "production" ? true :false,
            domain : process.envNODE_ENV === "production" ? "mydomain.com" :"localtest.me"
        }
    }));
```

This user asked a similar question but got no response [express-session dynamic cookie domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473089/express-session-dynamic-cookie-domain)

If I can't access the `req` object what are other options? I use nginx, is there something I can do with that? Maybe I can do dynamic env variables.
The only way I can think of solving this is to have multiple node app files (Which are gettings large) to server on different routes. this way I can create new server blocks that listen to different routes on different server blocks depending on servername. All that just to change like 20 text characters(the domain name)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, without a minimalistic working example, have tried something like this?

```js
 server.use((req, res, next) => {

    // do here what you want with req,res,next

    let middleware = session({
        secret: 'a;ldfnrlkf332',
        resave: true,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
        saveUninitialized: false,
        // cookie : {secure : false, domain : "lvh.me"}
        cookie: { 
            // secure: false, 
            secure : process.envNODE_ENV === "production" ? true :false,
            domain : process.envNODE_ENV === "production" ? "mydomain.com" :"localtest.me"
        }
    });

    // call middleware function
    middleware(req, res, next);

 });
```

`session` returns just a middleware function, which you can wrap.
https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L179

EDIT/NOTE: Perhaps it is not best.practice to create on every request a new mongodb store. You should work here with a cache/check if there is allready one.

Sadly there are no way to access the [`options`](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L88) object from outside, which would allow to manipulate the session instance.

Edit2, Another way is to create *n* stores, as much domains you have, (with the options you need) and call then based on the request domain the needed store:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    switch (req.headers.host) {

        case "example.com":
            store1(req, res, next)
            break;

        case "sub.example.com":
            store2(req, res, next)
            break;

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it appears that I have both domains up. I want to do more testing to make sure the sessions work properly. Just wanted to say thanks and update you. I will upvote this if I can.

Comment: @jackblank Im glad i could help you. Did this answer your question? If so please mark my solution as answer.